# How to make a dynamic css class whose name changes every visit to confuse scraper

Tags: plugins, php, functions, themes, css

I want to make the page classes changed dynamic depend on time or anything else to force the type of scraper that depend on my site classes

or the classes like content, entry-content .. etc.

How can I do that? and how I control with the new classes name to get the style from old classes?!

**Old class**

```
.entry-content{
 color:red;
 font-size:12pt;
}
```

**new class**

```
.timeNowis46421sdf{
 color:red;
 font-size:12pt;
}
```

Comment: No sure why you’d want to do this but you could in-line your styles and the add the class via jQuery.  Alternatively you could use wildcards in your style.css and then just randomize you’re classes on page load with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but it is possible.

You would use something like this for your CSS:

```
[class*='random-']{
    color:red;
    font-size:12pt;
}
```

That's just your stylesheet targeting any class that starts with `random-`.  You could change that to be whatever you want it to be, say `entry-` or whatever.  You'll just need to match it with the jQuery below.

Now, in your primary/main JS file, you'd want something like this, or take this entire code, make a new file and paste everything below into it. You'd have to enqueue that file though.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        if( $( '.entry-content' ).length > 0 ) {
            var newClassName = 'random-'+Math.floor( ( new Date() ).getTime() / 1000 );
            $( '.entry-content' ).addClass( newClassName ).removeClass( 'entry-content' );
        }
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

First thing we're doing is checking if there is an `.entry-content` on the page - I generally always run a check like this first because I don't want to bother executing anything unless there's something on the page to be effected.

Then we're generating a new class as a jQuery variable by combining `random-` with a string of numbers using the current date/time.

Lastly we're searching for the `.entry-content` class, adding the `random-1592183945` that we generated as a the `newClassName` variable, and then removing the `.entry-content` class.

And that's it.  Your CSS selector will recognize the class and apply style rules to it and each page load will generate a different class name every second, so scrapers should see them as being different.

Comment: thanks but how can I do it by PHP codes?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
<div class="entry-content random-<?php echo time(); ?>">
<style>
[class*='random-']{
    color:red;
    font-size:12pt;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That looks like the same CSS as the other answer. What's different here please?

Comment: whenever scraper scraping your sites then use the main class of sites. if you do use dynamic and random class CSS, then you can save your site's data in scrapping.

(site main class)
<div class="random-<?php echo time(); ?>"> 

(here is style)
<style>
[class*='random-']{
    color:red;
    font-size:12pt;
}</style>